# TS Set exclude multiple objects of same subtype

Tags: typescript, set, typing

I have an abstract class `Spell` with subclasses for concrete instantiation.

```
abstract class Spell {
    name: string
    manaCost: number

    constructor(name: string, manaCost: number) {
        this.name = name
        this.manaCost = manaCost
    }
}

class Fireball extends Spell { ... }
class Lightning extends Spell { ... }
```

I have a `Character` with a list of spells

```
class Character {
  spells: Spell[]

  addSpell(spell: Spell) {
    this.spells.push(spell)
  }
}
```

I would like to prevent multiple spell instances of the same type from being added to the character's `.spells` array, i.e only one `FireballSpell` instances can be added. I try using a `Set` instead of an array

```
class Character {
  spells: Set<Spell>

  addSpell(spell: Spell) {
    this.spells.add(spell)
  }
}
```

However, because the spells are different instances, they are not considered duplicates and are allowed to be added.

```
const character = new Character()
character.addSpell(new Fireball())
character.addSpell(new Fireball())
console.log(character.spells.size) // 2, should be 1
```

What is the correct declaration for this?

Comment: Could you please [edit] to make the code a [mre]?  It would make sense to initialize `spells` so that others can test easily (`2, should be 1`, instead of `RUNTIME ERROR, should be 1`). And the solution to this will depend on being able to identity the subtype programmatically, which means the bodies of `Lightning` and `Fireball` are potentially relevant. I could make them up myself, but then that means my solution will only be applicable if I guessed correctly or close enough.  Like, [here](https://tsplay.dev/WYeegW) is a guess that `name` will be strongly typed, but I'd rather not guess.

Comment: @michael-moreno do you need TYPES or CODE?

Comment: @michael-moreno do you need to IGNORE duplicates or ERROR?

Answer (score 0):

```
type SpellName = 'Fireball' | 'Lightning' // or enum

// spell name is generic, it freezes constructor arg
// You may limit it to `extends SpellName` if you want 
abstract class Spell<Name = string> {
  name: Name
  manaCost: number

  constructor(name: Name, manaCost: number) {
    this.name = name
    this.manaCost = manaCost
  }
}

class Fireball extends Spell<'Fireball'> {
  constructor() {
    super("Fireball", 123);
  }
}
class Lightning extends Spell<'Lightning'> {
  constructor() {
    super("Lightning", 234);
  }
}

// Often a map of those is made, this forces every SpellName to be used
const spellMap: {[K in SpellName]: new () => Spell<K>} = {
  Fireball,
  Lightning
}


class Character {
  spellsMap: Map<string, Spell> = new Map();
  spells: Spell[] = [];

  addByName(spell: SpellName) {
    return this.addSpell(new spellMap[spell]())
  }
  addSpell(spell: Spell) {

    // override spell in the Map<string, Spell>
    this.spellsMap.set(spell.name, spell);
    // add spell to Array<Spell> if missing
    if (!this.spells.find(s => s.name === spell.name)) {
      // ^ could've use `![].every` or `[].some` but `find` may be more straightforward for beginners
      this.spells.push(spell)
    }
    // well, the Set<Spell> would be same as Array<Spell>

    console.log('spells: ', this.spells, this.spellsMap)
  }
}

const character = new Character()
character.addSpell(new Fireball()) // spells: [Fireball] Map(1){"Fireball"=>Fireball}
character.addSpell(new Fireball()) // spells: [Fireball] Map(1){"Fireball"=>Fireball}
character.addSpell(new Lightning()) // spells: [Fireball,Lightning] Map(1){"Fireball"=>Fireball,"Lightning"=>Lightning}
```

(code template from jcalz comment)

Comment: I'm not sure why you're posting code from my comments as answers instead of letting me do it once the OP responds, but if you're going to do that, could you explain what it's doing instead of posting a code-only answer?

Comment: @jcalz I was meaning I've copied template from your comment rather then from OP's post. Explanation point acepted.